# dateformatting in xcode 7.2 not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

Working with iOS 9 i have a problem with date formatting, I tried so much but not find any solution.Problem is i have a date string "4/6/2016 12:47:00 PM" from which i want to get date with the same format .so am using date formatter

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
```

but every time am getting this format 2016-04-06 07:47:00 +0000

any help

Comment: That seems correct for default logging output, given no specified time zone.  Try displaying your date after calling -[df stringFromDate:]

Comment: 2016-04-06 07:47:00 +0000 am getting this one after calling [df stringFromDate:];

Comment: What is the locale of the device you're testing on?

Comment: Try setting the df.timeZone to different values and see if that helps.

Comment: English United States

Comment: The `2016-04-06 07:47:00 +0000` is the output that you'd get if you'd `NSLog` the `NSDate` object, not the string you created from the date formatter. Are you 100% sure you're looking at the string result of `stringFromDate` and not some `NSDate` object? You say you had a string `4/6/2016 12:47:00 PM`: So if you use `dateFromString`, you'd get a `NSDate` object (which if you `NSLog` that `NSDate` object, you'd see that result you described). If you want to take that date and convert it to a string again, you'd then use `stringFromDate` with the same formatter.

Comment: Thanks @Rob  for your valuable comment